# How to update selected rows in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have to update dataframe  with the new date, But dataframe is always original state. So the end of this loop will be updated only the iterated last ID result. How can i solve this.

```
list_rid=[1,2,3]
for id in list_rid:
        new_date = date.today() - timedelta(days = 1)
        df= df.withColumn("col_", F.when(F.col('ID')==id, new_date).cast("date"))
```

expect only those ID date need to update not any rows.

Comment: can you post the dataframe you have before (`df.show(truncate=False)`) and what you're expecting after the loop?

Answer (score 1):

The way to approach this in `PySpark` is to combine its `F.col().isin()` operation with a `PySpark` `IF` statement:

```
df.withColumn('col_', F.when(F.col('ID').isin(list_rid), new_date).otherwise(F.col('col')))
```

Full reproducible example:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('spark_session').getOrCreate()

# Create an example dataframe
data = [(id, "19300101") for id in range(1, 5)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("ID", "col"))
df = df.withColumn("col", F.to_date('col', format='yyyyMMdd'))
df.show()

# +---+----------+
# | ID|       col|
# +---+----------+
# |  1|1930-01-01|
# |  2|1930-01-01|
# |  3|1930-01-01|
# |  4|1930-01-01|
# +---+----------+



# replace date for all ID's in list_rid
list_rid=[1,2,3]
new_date = date.today() - timedelta(days = 1)

df = (
    df
    .withColumn(
        'col_',
        F.when(F.col('ID').isin(list_rid), new_date)
        .otherwise(F.col('col'))
    )
)

df.show()

# +---+----------+----------+
# | ID|       col|      col_|
# +---+----------+----------+
# |  1|1930-01-01|2023-05-17|
# |  2|1930-01-01|2023-05-17|
# |  3|1930-01-01|2023-05-17|
# |  4|1930-01-01|1930-01-01|
# +---+----------+----------+
```